# How to call functions from another js file in app.js

Tags: react-native

I currently have a working version of my application, however I wrote everything inside the app.js file and would like to clean it up. I want to take one of the functions I currently have in my app.js file and write a new js file to call that function in app.js
I have tried making a new js file and exporting the function:

`export myFunction (){...}`

then in my app.js

`I import {myFunction} from './new.js';`

and I call the function  myFunction()

I get the error: error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: **C:\Users\user\Desktop\GitHub\CIS498\TEST\node_modules\react-native\scripts\rwFile.js: Unexpected token (2:20)**

```
1 |
2 |    export myFunction()
  |                     ^
3 |   {
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Put your code which is causing the problem. This information you have provided is insufficient.

Comment: rwFile.js   export myFunction()
  {
    const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
    var path = dirs.DocumentDir + '/my.csv';
    RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(path)
      .then((exist) => {
        if(exist === false){
          RNFetchBlob.fs.writeStream(path, 'base64', true)
              .then((stream) => {
             stream.write(RNFetchBlob.base64.encode('licNum, DOB, fName, lName, address, town, state, gender ' + '\n'))
             return stream.close()
         })
    }
    })
  }

app.js 
other import statements...
import {myFunction} from './rwFile.js';
myFunction();

Comment: So the problem appears to be in `rwFile.js`, the function declaration should be like.. `export function myFunction(){...}` or like the one which is provided in the answer suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told Javascript what myFunction is. Try:

```
function myFunction() { ... }

module.exports = {
  myFunction
}
```